# Why can i download pdf file from mobile chrome in an android emulator, but can't in real phones?

Tags: javascript, express, google-chrome, mobile, save-as

I'm trying to download a pdf file in a webapp served by an express server, using [file-saver](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-saver) and [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), and it works fine in desktop browsers and in mobile chrome from android emulator (Pixel 2 API 29), but doesn't work in any real phones I've tested. The request hits the server and returns normally, but nothing happens on the browser, no error messages, nothing.

Here's the code server-side:

```
app.get("/extratoDownload", (req, res) => {
  console.log("GET /extratoDownload -- " + Date());
  res.sendFile("/pdfs/extratoGerado.pdf", { root: "." });
});
```

Here's the code client-side:

```
axios
  .get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_APIURL}/extratoDownload`, {
    responseType: "blob"
  })
  .then(
    res => {
      const pdfBlob = new Blob([res.data], {
        type: "application/pdf"
      });
      const pdfName =
        "extratoVendedor" +
        refHome.state.mes +
        refHome.state.ano +
        ".pdf";
      saveAs(pdfBlob, pdfName);
    },
    erroGetPdf =>
      "Erro ao obter pdf do servidor:\n" + erroGetPdf.message
  )
```